# Power on iRobot Create 2 via serial port

Tags: irobot-create

I have Arduino talk with Create 2 via serial interface. But before sending commands to the robot, I have to power it on by manually pushing the power button on the robot. How to make the robot turned on via that mini din 7 port, instead of pushing that power button? 
I notice when plugin iRobot serial-2-USB cable into that port on the robot, the robot is immediately turned on, ready for received the first command (command 128), so apparently there is way to turn on the robot via that port.

Comment: This question (http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/irobot-create-2-powering-up-after-sleep) may have the answers you are looking for

Comment: That indeed has the answer: pull BRC pin down and the bot will wake up. Thanks @Jonathan!