# Wake up iRobot Create 2 while on dock

Tags: irobot-create

I have a 7 pin cable connected to the OI port of my Create 2. While the Create is on the floor away from the dock, if I touch the BRC pin (7) to the ground pin (5), the Create wakes up, makes a beep, and the green Clean button light turns on.

However, if I put the Create on the dock and let it sit for several minutes and then touch the BRC pin to the ground pin, nothing happens.

Is there a method for waking up/starting the Create while it is on the dock/charging?

(Note: I have seen this answer and it does not solve the issue [IRobot Create 2: Powering Up after Sleep](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/irobot-create-2-powering-up-after-sleep))

If I send a command or try to fetch sensor data after the Create has been sitting on the dock for several minutes, I get no response and the Create doesn't do anything (no lights, sounds, movements, etc).

While the Create is already awake, the response from a restart command (0x7) looks like this

```
bl-start
STR730
bootloader id: #x4718535E 7DDBCFFF
bootloader info rev: #xF000
bootloader rev: #x0001
2007-05-14-1715-L
```

EDIT: simplified the scope of the question.

EDIT 2: added info from Jonathan's questions.

Comment: What happens if you send a command or try to fetch sensor data? Also, what SW release does your robot have on it? (This will help me understand what the robot should be doing while on the dock).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jonathan. I've added the info to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

With the firmware you have, the robot does not sleep on the dock. Assuming the baud rates are correct, it will still respond to sensor fetches and should respond to the 'clean' request.
Pulsing the BRC pin could be changing the baud rate or could be doing some other unintentional behavior.