# iRobot Create 2 Wake over Serial on Rpi

Tags: irobot-create, python, serial, roomba

So this thread is similiar to this one:
[IRobot Create 2: Powering Up after Sleep](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/irobot-create-2-powering-up-after-sleep/7900?newreg=d47bb1b89de04d3b80d2fbfa42f0acd3)

All except I am trying to do this on an RPi.

I have followed these intstruction:
https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/RaspberryPi_Tutorial.pdf

I have put together the little RPi top that uses the buffering chip. Everything is working great.

However I cannot get it to wake over serial!

iRobot even has examples of this, I can't get it to work.

From here:
https://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/RoboCam-WebInterface.pdf
They show:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # as opposed to GPIO.BOARD # Uses 'import RPi.GPIO as GPIO'
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT) # pin 17 connects to Create2 BRC pin
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW) # pulse BRC low to wake up irobot and listen at default baud
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
```

They also have an example python script with this code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)   # BCM for GPIO numbering  
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT) # Make pin 17 (which is hooked up to the BRC pin) an output

while True:
    # Pulse the BRC pin at a low duty cycle to keep Roomba awake.
    GPIO.output(17, False)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(17, True)
    sleep(59)
```

Neither work.

Now this code runs perfectly fine without issue on the RPi. I pip installed all the right libraries. I am using Python3.7, every other function over serial is working fine.

But this wake command does not work. It also does not prevent it from going back to sleep!

I followed the instruction for making the 3.3v to Logic circuit exactly from here:
https://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Serial_to_33V_Logic.pdf
Again I made the one at the bottom with the '5V-tolerant 3.3V buffer' which does explicitly show the green pin being soldered to IO17. Which is where I soldered it.

The only different is I put the pi hat on a RPi 3 rather than an RPi, I assume the GPIO pins still align the same?

Can anyone think of any more ideas? I am running out of them myself.

Comment: I have also tried running this off a fresh reboot of the PI. No luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a bug in the create2 firmware. If you email iRobot they can send you an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this tutorial which is for RPi-3

https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/

Also can you share the picture of your RPi-3 and point out your soldered "green pin"?